# How to use images/icons as labels in highcharter? R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I am using highcharter to make a bar plot, in a shiny app, but I am having troubles displaying icons as labels on the x-axis. The goal is to use svg images from a file placed in the working directory.

I have attached an example below and I have searched inspiration in the following two links but I am having troubles getting the JS-function into R shiny - setup.
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-comparison
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16609

I though the problem was the backslach before quotation marks, but when I display the icon in my app  just using
`tags$div(HTML("<img src = \"logoA.svg\">"))`, it displays perfectly (logoA.svg is placed in the www folder)

Any suggestions how to solve this?

```
  
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)


## app.R ##
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot<- renderHighchart({
    
    Label1<- c("A","A","B","B")
    Label2<- c("1","2","1","2")
    Val<- runif(4,0,100)
    col<-c("#d21e1e","#009beb","#ff5a1a","#009beb")
    Data<-data.frame(Label1,Label2,Val,col)
 
    highchart(type="chart") %>%
      hc_add_series(data = Data,type = "column",
                    hcaes(x = Label1,
                          y = Val,
                          group = Label2,
                          color = col),
                    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.mean}'))%>%
      hc_legend(enabled = F)%>% 
      hc_xAxis(type= 'category', useHTML=T, labels=list(formatter = JS("function(){
                                                          if(this.value == 'A'){
                                                            return '<img src=\"logoA.svg\"></img>';
                                                          }else if(this.value == 'B')
                                                            return '<img src=\"logoB.svg\"></img>';
                                                          }")) )

  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(
    HTML("<img src=\"logoA.svg\"></img>")
  ),
  
  highchartOutput("plot")
  
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, just move the `useHTML=T` parameter from the `hc_xAxis` function to the `labels` list:

```
    highchart(type = "chart") %>%
        hc_add_series(
            data = Data,
            type = "column",
            hcaes(
                x = Label1,
                y = Val,
                group = Label2,
                color = col
            ),
            dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.mean}')
        ) %>%
        hc_legend(enabled = F) %>%
        hc_xAxis(type = 'category',
                 labels = list(
                     formatter = JS(
                         "function(){
                              if(this.value == 'A'){
                                return '<img src=\"logoA.svg\"></img>';
                              }else if(this.value == 'B')
                                return '<img src=\"logoB.svg\"></img>';
                              }"
                     ),
                     useHTML = T
                 ))
```

Comment: thank you - it works! 

I also needed to specifiy the width and height like this:
return '<img src = \"LogoA.svg\" width=\"50\" height=\"60\">'